# Horizontally scrollable cell within vertically scrollable collection view: best way to implement?

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I already have a `UICollectionView` whose layout is of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` type and scroll direction is **vertical**. Something similar to this (from [this site](https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/))

[image: App Store]

Now I need to add some sections to this collection view whose cells can show a **horizontally scrollable collection** of custom cells that will be different from the ones I already have. Something similar to this (also from [this site](https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/)):

[image]

I also need the items there to have a width less than the screen's width and to be able to **see part of the next and previous items**.

Behaviour of the horizontal scrolling could be either **continuous** like, let's say, the "Stories" section in Facebook app:

[image: Facebook app]

or with **paging** like in the `App Store` app I showed before.

Question: which would be the best way to implement this?

**A)** Outer collection view (vertical scroll)
     --> custom cell containing an **inner collection view** (horizontal scroll)
       --> items are inner collection view's cells

In this case, how would pagination be implemented?

**B)** Outer collection view (vertical scroll)
     --> custom cell containing a **scroll view** (horizontal scroll)
       --> items are views added as scroll view's subviews

In this case, how would pagination be implemented?

**C)** A different approach would be the most appropriate?

**EDIT:** another consideration: items to be horizontally scrollable will be different for iPhone and iPad devices.